# Erro Assinatura Conflitante

Tags: android

Ola, estou com um grande problema

Eu tenho um APK para android que rodava tudo certinho, mas tive um problema com a maquina em que estava o projeto e tive que trocar de maquina,
instalei tudo certinho na maquina nova, esta rodando tudo beleza.

Mas quando gero um APK e tento instalar ele em um celular que já rodava o mesmo APK ele da esse erro

"Erro Assinatura Conflitante"

Mas antes eu conseguia atualizar normal dps que troquei de maquina nao consigo mais atualizar os APK.

Como consigo essa assinatura anterior ? o que fazer para resolver isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo seu erro isso pode acontecer por basicamente três motivos:

1. Se for a versão release do APK você usou uma KeyStore diferente da usada anteriormente para assinar o APK, sendo que o APK deve sempre ser assinado com a mesma KeyStore.
2. Você possui a versão release instalado no aparelho e está tentando instalar a versão debug por cima, ou vice versa.
3. Você está tentando instalar uma nova versão debug que foi criada em uma máquina diferente, sendo que o SDK do android gera uma keystore diferente em cada máquina que ele é instalado

No seu caso o mais provável seja o terceiro caso, já que você trocou de máquina. Isso poderia ser resolvido com o backup do *$HOME/.android/debug.keystore* (no windows o $HOME equivale a pasta do usuário c:\users\nomedousuario)

Mas em todos os casos, desinstalar o aplicativo manualmente do aparelho também resolve o problema.

Answer (score 0):

A assinatura geralmente fica na pasta do projeto, mas basta desinstalar o app do celular que vai dar certo.